# Not able to activate a product id for in-app billing in my google play console

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I have an application where i added in-app billing library and setup of code is done , i have uploaded my aab file to closed testing and the app has been reviewed and approved , when i create a product id and try to activate , i keep getting errors , if anyone could help with this , Thank you

- When i click on 'Activate' , this is the error i'm getting

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (5DB42EFE -> this number keeps changing 
everytime)
```

- This is a screenshot of the error generated
  [image]

Comment: I am suffering from this problem. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Well basically i had to create a different one that i never used in my google console account ( basically use a unique and different naming )

Comment: Did you have to create a new one or just change the app's naming?

Comment: I had to actually create a new one and made it is unique  from all the other i made before

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem some time ago. If you are trying to create a subscription, then try changing the grace period on that subscription. Initially I tried to make it 30 days and I always get the same error message. But when I change it to 3 or 7 days, everything works normally. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm working with in-app product , for some reason i had two products which i could not enable then suddenly changed the product id to another name and it worked  , i still do not know why

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I found out that this problem is related to the "payment profile" in my case I had previously canceled it but soon afterwards I recreated the profile adding a new payment method but I discovered that it is not that simple because after you cancel your payment profile all your related accounts get some kind of issue. So the solution was to contact "google pay" support and ask them to reactivate my payment account. Then everything started working properly again.